# ThreadPool throws java.util.concurrent.FutureTask cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, exception, queue, threadpool, comparable

I've got a very simple program:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        class MyThread2 implements Runnable{
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                            System.out.println("Terminated!");
                            throw new InterruptedException();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                2,
                2,
                1,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(),
                Executors.defaultThreadFactory());
        executor.submit(new MyThread2());
        executor.submit(new MyThread2());
        executor.submit(new MyThread2());
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
```

On running it using maven, it prints:

```
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.siftUpComparable (PriorityBlockingQueue.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.offer (PriorityBlockingQueue.java:489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1371)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at MyThreadFactory.main (MyThreadFactory.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

And hangs. I don't have any "Comparable" implementation for `PriorityBlockingQueue` in my program, where does this exception came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PriorityBlockingQueue` expects *comparable* elements, which your `MyThread2` class fails to provide. So you do have `Comparable` in your program, but it's an internal thing.

Change your `executor` to use `LinkedBlockingQueue`, if you can't provide comparable elements, for example. Or obviously, find a way to "explain" how to compare your tasks that you submit (by implementing `Comparable`).

---

Now that I think about it, it would have been very cool if the API could detect that. So if you provide a `PriorityBlockingQueue` and call `submit(new MyThread2())`, *at compile time*, this would have detected and a compile time error raised (saying that `MyThread2` is not a `Comparable`). Unfortunately this is not the case in this API, nor I think it's possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

Exception is thrown, because priority blocking queue doesn't know, how to compare its elements. It does not permit non-comparable objects. You have two options:

1. Make queue elements implement comparable
2. Provide comparator for queue in constructor

Checkout PriorityBlocking queue javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html